# VNC Not Connecting to saved connection

Tags: networking, vnc

I am having difficulty with a VNC problem, it is a connection to a server that I use on a daily basis. however today I tried to select the saved connection and it failed to connect, displaying the Failed to connect to server message... this has only happened twice but I fail to see how it can work for months then just all of a sudden not connect.

My colleagues can connect to the same server through VNC but I get the error message which suggests its a problem with my machine...

I also have the password for the connection saved so it should automatically connect. Can anyone suggest how I would restore the connection?

Comment: if you are connecting via computer name, make sure it resolves to an IP address. If connecting to an IP, make sure it has not changed.

Comment: @RichieFrame I should've really replied to you at the time but I thought I'd say that if I could connect to it before that suggests the name does resolve to an IP Address and if it is a server the address would be static so it would not have changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the problem, it was a bad IP address on my machine. I released and renewed my IP and ran arp -d on the server this restored the connection.